# Symfony2: How to render partial in Twig extension

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a already working Twig extension in my Symfony2 app:

```
namespace Company\MyBundle\Service;

class MyExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    // ...
}
```

I now want to create a Twig function, which itselfs takes some data and renders a partial template. But my question is: *how do I get a new templating instance in my twig extension service?*

Here is my current config:

```
services:
    twig.extension.my_extensions:
        class: Company\MyBundle\Service\TwigExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

If I now add `arguments: [@templating]` to the config, I get an (understandable) circular reference exception.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but you could try to change the scope of the templating engine to prototype so there will be always a new object injected. See here for more on scopes: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems one of the recommended [simple ways](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2347#issuecomment-2838590) is to inject the container directly and retrieve the templating engine from there.  As you've seen, injecting in the templating engine directly causes a circular reference exception.

So, inject in `@service_container` and you should be good.  This seems to be the approach taken by bundles such as the [FOSFacebookBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/facebook.xml#L29) as well.